# Как заполнить таблицу MySQL датами?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Есть таблица Calendar

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, как можно заполнить caldate DATE датами от 01-01-2019 до 31-12-2019?

Comment: Версия MySQL какая?

Comment: @Akina Server version: 8.0.19 MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
INSERT INTO calendar (caldate, iduser)  -- или UPDATE? ... 
WITH RECURSIVE
cte AS (   SELECT '2019-01-01' as `date`
         UNION ALL
           SELECT `date` + INTERVAL 1 DAY
           FROM cte
           WHERE `date` < '2019-12-31' )
SELECT cte.`date`, user.id
FROM cte
CROSS JOIN user;
```

Comment: 22:13:26 WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (   SELECT '2019-01-01' as `date`          UNION ALL            SELECT `date` + INTERVAL 1 DAY            FROM cte            WHERE `date` < '2019-12-31' ) INSERT INTO calendar (caldate) SELECT `date` FROM cte Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO calendar (caldate) SELECT `date` FROM cte' at line 7 0.015 sec   Что я делаю не так?

Comment: @skipperoker Точно - всё время на это накалываюсь, уже не первый год... поправил. PS. Будете пробовать - начинайте с недели, а не сразу на год вперёд...

Comment: спасибо, у меня составной первичный код (caldate, user_iduser), поэтому мне и user_iduser нужно заполнять.

Comment: @skipperoker А откуда он будет браться, этот набор значений для user_iduser? вот это и добавляй в источник данных запроса (как ещё один CTE, наверное). И соответственно CROSS JOIN.

Comment: он берется из таблицы user

Comment: Если он там уникальный - просто добавить `user` во FROM. Иначе - сделать DISTINCT выборку в CTE.

Comment: вернее так: user_iduser - это внешний ключ таблицы calendar для связи с таблицей user. То есть связь  user_iduser (в таблице calendar, является и pk и fk, не уникальное поле) - iduser (в таблице user, уникальное поле, pk). Если не сложно, можете дополнить код в ответе с учетом user_iduser?

Comment: @skipperoker Обновил ответ.

Comment: спасибо, огонь!)